# How to access section settings values in CSS file

Tags: css, schema, shopify, settings

In one of my theme files I give the site-creator the ability to set the `background-size` property of an element using the Schema

**sections/hero.liquid**

```
{% schema %}

{
  "name": "Hero",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "Image",
      "info": "1400 x 700 recommended"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "bg_img_size_desktop",
      "label": "Image Size (for desktop):",
      "default": "cover",
      "info": "Possible values: cover, contain, 310%..." 
    },
    ...
```

and now I would like to access that value in my theme's CSS file.

**assets/main.scss.liquid**

```
.hero__image {
   background-size: {{ section.settings.bg_img_size_desktop }};
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the liquid file containing the CSS has access to `section.settings` as when the CSS is rendered, it displays:

```
.hero__image {
   background-size: ;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? or do I have to include that CSS in the theme file? This works:

**sections/hero.liquid**

```
<style>
    .hero__image {
       background-size: {{ section.settings.bg_img_size_desktop }};
    }
</style>
```

but I feel like there's got to be a way to keep that dynamic CSS with the rest of the CSS for the theme. If anyone in the know has any guidance here, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the section values into theme main SCSS files, you only access those values into the same section files ie(hero.liquid) in your case.

To use the main SCSS to handle these you may assign a unique class based on these values and then use those classes to apply style into main SCSS files.

Like when you select an option value like `cover` then you assign the class like this snippet

```
<div class="bg-{{section.settings.bg_img_size_desktop }}"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="{% section.settings.bg_img_size_desktop == 'cover' %}custom class{% endif %}"></div>
```

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I can do the custom class names for properties that have constants as their values, but for something like `background-image` where the value could literally be anything, I'll have to add the value in the theme section file - not the end of the world, i suppose. Thanks for clearing that up for me.